# View source path

Tags: shotcut

I dragged a clip file to the timeline, and it was given a caption as the file name.

Is there a way to view the source directory of a clip? I can't find it on the properties.

Is there a way to always view it?

Motivation: I have a bunch of clips with the same name that differ by their directories.

Possible solution: write a python script that for each chain in the xml (.mlt) sets the caption as the resource property.

---

Related: when moving a source clip to a different location, is editing the xml the only way to update it?

---

Not many questions are posted on Shotcut here. I posted the same question on their forum.